# How to dynamically change the location in google map using the <iframe> tag

Tags: php, iframe

I am trying to change the google map location dynamically by using user location present in database.

My php code is just an example

```
<?php

   $state = 'Uttar Pradesh';  
   $city = 'Lucknow';
   $country = 'India';

 ?>



 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d227822.55046115004!2d80.80242499245689!3d26.848622942020608!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x399bfd991f32b16b%3A0x93ccba8909978be7!2sLucknow%2C+Uttar+Pradesh!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1478094637337" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use these variables somewhere in the code? And doesn't php mean it runs on the server? Maybe try JavaScript instead?